# Allure Create Screenshot - Selenium

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testing, allure

I'm having trouble taking screenshots with allure.
I have configured my interface in which in case of failure test I call the function whose task is to create a screenshot in the report. However, this does not work. Screenshot are not created.

Below is my interface:

```
package Test;

import Test.resources.Base;
import io.qameta.allure.Allure;
import io.qameta.allure.Attachment;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ListenersT extends Base implements ITestListener {
    Base b = new Base();


    public void onFinish(ITestContext arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    public void onStart(ITestContext arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage(ITestResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //screenshot

        try {
            b.getScreenshot(result.getName());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Object testClass = result.getInstance();
        WebDriver driver = ((Base) testClass).getDriver();
        if(driver instanceof  WebDriver) {
            takeScreenshot(driver);
        }
    }

    @Attachment(value = "Page screenshot", type ="image/png")
    public byte[] takeScreenshot(WebDriver driver) {
        byte[] screenshotAs = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
        return screenshotAs;
    }


    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onTestStart(ITestResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

And here is my base class form which extend my interface:

```
package Test.resources;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Listeners;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Base {

    public static WebDriver driver;


    public WebDriver initializeDriver() throws IOException {

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\main\\java\\Test\\resources\\data.properties");
        prop.load(fis);

        Properties propBuykers = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fisBuykers = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\main\\java\\Test\\resources\\data.propertiesBuykers");
        propBuykers.load(fisBuykers);

        String browserName;

        if(System.getProperty("browser") == null) {
            browserName = "chrome";
        }
        else {
            browserName = System.getProperty("browser");
        }


        //String browserName = prop.getProperty("browser");

        if(browserName.contains("chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver2.exe");
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();


            if(browserName.contains("headless")) {
                options.addArguments("headless");
            }
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        }
        else if(browserName.equals("firefox")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GeckoDriver\\geckodriver.exe");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
        else if(browserName.equals("edge")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MicrosoftWebDriver\\msedgedriver.exe");
            driver = new EdgeDriver();
        }

        else if (browserName.equals("remoteBrowser")) {
            DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
            caps.setCapability("platform", "Windows 10");
            caps.setCapability("version", "66.0");

            RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("g42664-b435-4a95-9b68-f43b51a43134@ondemand.eu-central-1.saucelabs.com:443/wd/hub"), caps);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            return driver;
        }

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        return driver;
    }

    public void getScreenshot(String result) throws IOException {
        File src = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(src, new File("C://s//"+result+"screenshot.png"));
    }

    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }
}
```

Please help me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try the file path as `C:\\s\\"+result+"screenshot.png"`

It should be backward slash and not forward.

**Note:- I would suggest not to use hard coded path and get the directory path.

```
File f = new File("testPictures.txt");
String absolute = f.getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I think the path is good because the screenshots are saved to the folder. Right, I'll change the path soon. The difference is that these screens are not related to allure. For allure I created this: ```


    @Attachment(value = "Page screenshot", type ="image/png")
    public byte[] takeScreenshot(WebDriver driver) {
        byte[] screenshotAs = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
        return screenshotAs;
    }```